# Можно ли написать простой эмулятор взаимодействия сетевых устройств на Python?

Tags: python, сеть, cisco-packet-tracer

Уважаемые эксперты. Хочу написать мини-эмулятор сетевых устройств на python. очень упрощенный аналог GNS3 или Cisco Packet Tracer. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли для python модули для моделирования работы определенных сетевых устройств? Так чтобы в коде можно было задать их базовые параметры и смоделировать взаимодействие.

Answer (score 1):

Взгляните на эти проекты:

https://github.com/TheTincho/nemu

https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Introduction-to-Mininet

Возможно это то что вы ищите